# Any idea why using jquery-ajax some img src are preppended with '%20'?

Tags: php, jquery

After a .load() call some content (with images) some of the user's profile image path get broken...

And i am not sure if is a coincidence but it will only happen with the opengraph's ones:

one example;

Iam trying to recive `<div class="user"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/652286316/picture" /></div>`

But i get `<div class="user"><img src="%20https://graph.facebook.com/652286316/picture" /></div>`

Any idea why could this happen?

Comment: you might have added a space in front of the url ..!!

Comment: Strange...well, as I'm sure you've figured out, the `%20` is an HTML encoded space character, but without seeing the page that's feeding your load script, it will be hard to see where the space could be coming from. Are you explicitly telling jQuery to expect an HTML result too?

Comment: the problem is that when i load the page without ajax the image path is fine, only when loading in ajax :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wanted to add that if you don't have access to the script feeding you the src for the image (eg when getting data from some external service), you can always replace the `%20` using something like this (in javascript)

```
function str_replace(needle, replacement, haystack) {
var temp = haystack.split(needle);
return temp.join(replacement);
}
```

and then use

```
var $new_src =  str_replace('%20', '', $old_src);
```

please note that this assumes that ALL spaces - `%20` - are unwanted in your img src, which might not be the case

ps. : this does NOT fix the problem, just avoids it.. you might want to see what's wrong with your code

Answer (score 2):

%20 is usually a whitespace ( ) URI encoded. For more info:
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 1):

you might have added a space in front of the url.Remove those space and you will be ok...

or you can strip spaces before inputting in the src field.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to trim the images names. In this way you will prevent any trailing spaces not only in front, but in the end of the image name. For your further projects: Also a whitespace in the name of the avatar could cause problems. And you should replace it with an underscore `'_'`, or a dash `'-'`.

```
trim( str_replace(' ', '_', $imgName ) );
```